# Read from anonymous / non-persisted memory-mapped file in Java

Tags: java, io, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

Java supports [memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) through a [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) retrieved via [`FileChannel#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-). These files allow multiple processes to share memory, among other uses.

As noted in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), there are two types of memory-mapped files:

> #### Persisted
>
> Persisted files are associated with a source file on a disk. The data is saved to the source file on the disk once the last process is finished. These memory-mapped files are suitable for working with extremely large source files.
>
> #### Non-persisted
>
> Non-persisted files are not associated with a file on a disk. When the last process has finished working with the file, the data is lost. These files are suitable for creating shared memory for inter-process communications (IPC).

Persisted memory-mapped files are easily acquirable via `FileChannel#map`. Non-persisted (anonymous) files, however, cannot be acquired in this manner. In Python, for example, with [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html), one can pass `-1` as the file number and unique tag names (in Windows) to acquire segments of an anonymous memory-mapped file.

1. Is it possible to read from an anonymous / non-persisted memory-mapped file in Java?
2. If so, is it possible (in Windows) to specify tag names to map anonymous file data?

Comment: I don't see jdk code passing appropriate flags to native code for anonymous mapping, so it appears it s not possible.